# Package calculating slopes fpr GPCM in R

Tags: r

The generalized partial credit model has two parameters, one is the threshold and the other one is the slope. I have calculated yet with the package ERM and the function PCM to get some thresholds, but with this package and this function I can't find any slopes.

Do you know a package which includes this function and can you send me an example, please?

Thank you so much,
Greets Hannah

Answer (score 0):

This is a MarkMail search for the topic:

http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project+generalized+partial+credit+model#query:list%3Aorg.r-project%20generalized%20partial%20credit%20model+page:1+mid:fn6v55rnbofn5n6d+state:results

Sadly, the Markmail search engine is no longer avaialble, so the search would need to be done at the Google Advanced search page and that then retrieves: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/140244.html.  I checked to see whether the cited package "plink" was still avaialble and find that it installs without difficulty